# Periodicals/magazines/blogs for cinematography?

Tags: camera

I want to stay up-to-date on cinematography techniques -- not just regurgitated press releases on camera technology. What regularly updated resources (not books) should I follow to continually learn the craft of cinematography?

Note: this is a re-post of [a question that was closed as off-topic](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/645/good-periodicals-magazines-blogs-for-cinematography) on Photography - Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

For basics in digital cinema the [Vimeo School](http://vimeo.com/videoschool) is a great start.

There are tons of blogs for cinematography.

One of the most interesting blogs that covers gear and on the set experiences
is by noted DP, Philip Bloom, a real major force in modern digital cinema:
http://philipbloom.net/blog/

Coen Brothers too:
http://thecoenbrothers.blogspot.com/?zx=2bb8d66a241d6286

For me the best way to find what's up is to see if your favorite
director, studio, camera manufacturer, or whatever has a blog via Google.

Answer (score 0):

[American Cinematographer](http://www.theasc.com/magazine/) is a magazine and the leading publication on cinematography. At the very least, you should be reading this.

Also, these forums have great communities:

- http://www.cinematography.com/
  One of the oldest communities on the web about cinematography.
- http://www.reduser.net/
  A forum focused on the Red Digital Cinema Camera Company but is very active and a good place to stay up-to-date on cinematography techniques.
- http://www.rogerdeakins.com/forum2/
  A website where 9-time Oscar nominee Roger Deakins answers questions submitted by readers.